# How to see if a ip address is on a network?

Tags: windows, ip

How would i go about seeing if an ip address is on a local network, you know see if it is connected?
Also, is there any way to do it using pre installed modules?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just ping it, check result...something like.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['ping', ADDRESS])
```

Comment: would that work for a wifi network though? And isn't that just pinging it? Will you actually see results ?

Comment: It is exactly using ping (hence why I said just ping it). using subprocess.call() will output to console by default.

Comment: Thanks :) Are there any other methods?

Comment: Sure...log onto router and check the arp table.

Comment: But Like using python. I just wanted to python to learn more about it but also for convenience. Is there a way to do it using if statements. As in if the ip is on the network print 'on the network'

Comment: The python language has no facilities for understanding what ip-addresses are in use on a network. Nor does any programming language for that matter. They all rely on the operating system to surface that information. Without knowing more about your environment, it will be impossible offer anything better than ping. What's wrong with ping>

Comment: Sure -- ping the broadcast address of your network. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_address